# Reverse proxy nginx to itself

Tags: nginx

I am currently hosting a single-page react app that is hosted in the URL root like so:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

I need to put the site behind an AWS elastic load balancer and at the same time change the path so everything is within a `/support` directory e.g. `http://example.com/index.html -> http://example.com/support/index.html`.

AWS ALBs do not support URL rewriting so I have to do this within the nginx config on the server. First of all I tried changing the config to:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location /support {
        alias   /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

This sort-of works but the URLs within the javascript content don't contain the `/support` path (e.g. they contain `http://example.com/script.js` instead of `http://example.com/support/script.js`).

I then tried creating a reverse-proxy config to proxy `/support` to `/`, which sadly put nginx in an infinite loop until it ran out of worker threads:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location /support {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
    }
    
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

}
```

I'm confused why requests are going into a reverse-proxy loop? Shouldn't `proxy_pass` remove the `/support` prefix before proxying the request, and therefore it shouldn't be "caught" again by the `/support` location?

Comment: `proxy_pass` does not rewrite anything. If it would, how could any server, which receives the request, know the `URI` to respond correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess.

Do you want to serve something on `/`?

If not - it is easy:

```
server
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location /support/
    {
        alias /var/www/html/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    location /
    {
        return 303 http://localhost/support$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Fiddle around with the ending slashes if it does not work (using them - or not - makes often a difference).

Use `alias` instead of `root` so that `/support` is not added to the `/var/www/html` folder.

Everything gets redirected to `/support`.

---

If you want to serve something on `/` which is different from `/support`:

Use `sub_filter` or `subs_filter` in `/support` to rewrite your source code links on-the-fly so that they will never use `/`.

If you have redirects inside your source code (or `proxy_pass` backend) - you need `proxy_redirect` and/or Lua to catch and change them on-the-fly.